# Encode string to specific code page

Tags: c#, string, encoding

im trying to encode string in Kamenicky code page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamenický_encoding), but i cannot succeed.
My code looks like:

```
var lines = "some text created in runtime";

Encoding kamenicky = Encoding.GetEncoding("CP895");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.Unicode;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(lines);
byte[] kamenickyBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, kamenicky, utfBytes);
var linesFinal = kamenicky.GetString(kamenickyBytes);
```

I always get this exception at first line of this code snippet:

> ArgumentException: 'CP895' is not a supported encoding name.

I tried GetEncoding(895) and GetEncoding('CP895') as well. Thanks for any answer or help.

Comment: Even if your code got past the first line, it doesn't make sense. You have a string `lines` which is a sequence of Unicode characters. You convert them to a sequence of bytes in UTF-8 encoding. You cannot decode these bytes using *any* encoding other than UTF-8. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you convert into UTF-8? Just use `lines.GetBytes(kamenicky)` - of course you still need to be able to get the right `Encoding` first...

Comment: i add declaration of lines, you can find out how do i create it. I thought all string variables created in visual studio is encoded with unicode (is unicode the same as UTF-8?). I have some real troubles here, can you be so kind and would you make me some introduction please?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx), CP895 is not supported in .net Framework.
(scroll down to see a list of all supported encodings)

You can write your own Encoding class by deriving from System.Text.Encoding.